# ASP.NET MVC controller won't receive my ajax get method data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here's a function that calls an ajax get method:

```
function getSubProjName(projectId) {
        console.log(projectId)
        var projectName = "";
        //ajax get request to get the subproject name
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSubProjName", "Home")',
            data: { projectId: projectId },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                projectName = response;
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        return projectName;
    }
```

I've checked it a billion times, `projectId` most definitely receives a value. If it helps, its always a numerical value.

Then I have a method in my controller that SHOULD receive the `projectId` and do something with it:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSubProjName([FromBody] string projectId)
{
    // some code here
    return Json(""); //return the code results back to the view
}
```

My problem is that I just can't get the controller to actually receive the data from the ajax call. All I get in my string `ProjectId`, in my controller method, is always `null`.

Comment: I guess i should have mentioned this. I have also tried changing the parameter type from string to int, but the end result didnt change

Comment: A `GET` method cannot possibly have a "body", so the `[FromBody]` attribute is all wrong. For a `GET`, you need to pass the `ProjectId` as part of the URL - `/api/GetSubprojectName/{ProjectId}` or something like that ....

Comment: I see. It seems your suggestion also led me on the right path. After changing
@Url.Action("GetSubProjName", "Home") to
@Url.Action("GetSubProjName", "Home",new { id = "projectId" }), it now successfully passed the data